# Use csv-data in clickhouse table

Tags: clickhouse

I have a problem when I want to use data from a csv-file in a table I have created. The database I created is called "test" and the table is created as following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testing
(
    `year` Int16, 
    `amount` Int16, 
    `rate` Float32, 
    `number` Int16
)
ENGINE = Log

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.033 sec.
```

I created all these columns to be able to cover all the data in the csv-file. I've read through the clickhouse documentation but just can't figure out how to get the data into my database.

I tested to do this:

```
$ cat test.csv | clickhouse-client \ >-- database =test\ >--query='INSERT test FORMAT CSV'

Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 1 (line 1, col 1): 2010,646,1.00,13
2010,2486,1.00,19
2010,8178,1.00,10
2010,15707,1.00,4
2010,15708,1.00,10
2010,15718,1.00,4
2010,16951,1.00,8
2010,17615,1.00,13
2010. Unrecognized token
```

Link: https://yadi.sk/d/ijJlmnBjsjBVc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure what your link leads to, but... all relevant information should be contained within your question itself, without requiring someone to visit another site.

Comment: You might be right, the link is to the csv-file I'm using. Just some test-data from yandex.

Comment: I would suggest including a small sample in your question (certainly doesn't need to be more than a few records for illustration purposes)

Comment: Now I have an example! :)

Comment: Looks like your command line call to `clickhouse-client` has errors in it. `--database =test` <= space allowed or not? `--query='INSERT test FORMAT CSV'` <= missing "`INTO`" I'm assuming the other characters (e.g. all the `\ >`) are some artifact of how you typed them into your shell?

Comment: This is what I write in the terminal: cat test.csv|clickhouse-client --database test --query='INSERT INTO test FORMAT CSV'

This is what I get in return:
Received exception from server (version 20.3.4):
Code: 60. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Table test.test doesn't exist.. 

The name of my database is test and the table is testing.

Comment: the table name is testing not test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat test.csv |clickhouse-client -d test -q 'INSERT into testing FORMAT CSV'

SELECT *
FROM test.testing

┌─year─┬─amount─┬─rate─┬─number─┐
│ 2010 │    646 │    1 │     13 │
│ 2010 │   2486 │    1 │     19 │
│ 2010 │   8178 │    1 │     10 │
│ 2010 │  15707 │    1 │      4 │
│ 2010 │  15708 │    1 │     10 │
│ 2010 │  15718 │    1 │      4 │
│ 2010 │  16951 │    1 │      8 │
│ 2010 │  17615 │    1 │     13 │
│ 2010 │  17616 │    1 │      4 │
│ 2010 │  17617 │    1 │      8 │
│ 2010 │  17618 │    1 │      9 │
```